# How to get a list of facebook groups for a user using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could someone point me in the right direction to how I can get a list of all the groups a specific user is connected to using the facebook graph api?

I have this:

```
$groups = $facebook->api( '/me/groups', 'GET', array( 'access_token=' => $membertoken ) );
```

If I use `print_r($groups)` I can see the array is returning all the groups, but how can I seperate the array to list just the group names and group ID into seperate strings so I can use them in a database etc?

Comment: I'm not sure i completely understand the question - if the API call is succeeding, and the values are in the API, can't you just extract the values you need by iterating through the array and pulling out the id and name elements from the list of groups?

Comment: You can try limiting the returned data by adding a `fields` to the request like this: `$facebook->api('/me/groups?fields=id,name')` but you that doesn't disable bookmark_order and administrator fields. However i don't understand why does it matter if other field are there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print "<h2>Here are the groups you follow:</h2>\n<ul>";
foreach ($groups['data'] as $group) {
    $group_name = $group['name'];
    $group_id = $group['id'];
    printf("<li>%s - ID = %s</li>\n", $group_name, $group_id);
}
print "</ul>";
```

Comment: cpilko your solution generates the following error...

         Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/post-to-groups.php on line 515 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/post-to-groups.php on line 515 

Any ideas?

Comment: My test bed just stopped working (Grrr) so I can't confirm this. Try it with array notation instead of object notation: `$groups['data']`, `$group['name']`...

Comment: Could you give me a code example on that please? Thanks in advance