# Get list of facebook groups using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of facebook groups for a user using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990123/how-to-get-a-list-of-facebook-groups-for-a-user-using-graph-api)

I am new to the C# SDK for facebook. Could someone tell me how I can get a list of the user groups using C#, I need them to populate a combobox with each group id.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990123/how-to-get-a-list-of-facebook-groups-for-a-user-using-graph-api)?

Comment: the duplicate indicated here does not refer to C# or the Facebook C# SDK, this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one.  Find another way to do it.  Sorry.